# Installing Express in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting error while installing Express to use in Node.js

I have attached screenshot of the command prompt.

I am not getting what this error is. Please let me know what this error say, so that I can fix it. [image: Screenshot]

Comment: DNS didn’t resolve in time; try again and confirm that you can connect to https://registry.npmjs.org/ in a browser.

Comment: @Ryan, I am able navigate to the registry.npmjs.org but still I am getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems:

- no internet connection
- DNS resolver misconfigured
- proxy settings required

You can try the following commands to narrow down the problem:

- `host registry.npmjs.org`
- `ping registry.npmjs.org`
- `curl http://registry.npmjs.org/`
- `curl https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Comment: 1. I have proper internet connectivity

2. Dont know how to check

3. Yes, i am behind proxy, which I had set using
`npm config set http-proxy http://abc.def.com/ghi:8080`

Still I am getting same error.

Comment: @Ashish: The port number goes after the host, not the path, for one. `http://abc.def.com:8080/ghi`